# How can I get big bubbles when I electrolyse water with detergent?

Tags: electrolysis

I've made carbon electrodes by putting 12V through a couple of short 15Ω pencils, but when I try to make hydrogen and oxygen bubbles from soapy water, I get tiny bubbles, smaller than table salt.

If I move the electrodes closer together, it's the same tiny bubbles, but a bit faster.

These don't catch fire very convincingly, and my daughter is unimpressed.

How can I get larger bubbles? Different electrodes? Higher voltage? Just shove the AC power in straight from the wall? :)

Comment: Kind of related (if you're looking for an at-home demo), and a hit for folks of all ages: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glowing_pickle_demonstration

Comment: @ToddMinehardt I did the electric pickle demo a few times over the years. Fun, but the electrocuted pickle smell is unexpectedly foul. ;-|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be tricky. The demos I've seen mostly rely on **collecting the hydrogen and oxygen, separately or together, and *then* bubbling them through a soap solution**.

If you've got the soap in the electrolyte, you might have a hard time getting anything more than two piles of foam, one of which is slightly flammable. I doubt the hydrogen foam would even rise in air; the volume percentage of gas is too low.

Comment: I know I did this demo when I was a trainee teacher (before I came to my senses) and I don't recall doing anything more than shoving the electrodes into a thimble-sized plastic beaker. Maybe I've blanked out collecting tubes...

Answer (score 1):

I found what presumably actually happened: https://edu.rsc.org/experiments/exploding-bubbles-of-hydrogen-and-oxygen/752.article

One very full beaker of water and electrolyte (bicarbonate of soda is apparently better than salt, lest you get chlorine instead of oxygen), a cork with two electrodes and a thin plastic tube, one end of which is level with the base of the cork to exclude as much air as possible, the other passing into a smaller plastic beaker of water with detergent or some other means of creating explosive form.

The combined gas is pre-mixed, and satisfactory loud.

I still have no memory of the primary beaker though: presumably the Thargons have been altering reality again, just to mess with me.